# installed java-jdk and changed environment path variable too but still ' javac ' command gives 'Not recognised' output

Tags: java, java-deployment-toolkit

I have installed the java-jdk(according to oracle instructions). And I have changed the environment path variable(path option)_ as well according to oracle. But still the command javac gives "not recognised"as output in command prompt. How to fix this?

[this is the Path option in Environment Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YwZV.png)

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin` needs to be on its own row in the list.  That user interface abstracts out the path separator `;`, so it does not work here at all.

Comment: Try restart computer, some active sessions of CMD might not realised the fact something has changed.